# How to apply only vertical changes while pathmorphing?

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I want to recreate the image shown below.

[image]

I'm struggeling with the "Non-conact-mode" part. This ist what I achieved so far:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1, every axis/.append style={font=\small}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick]

        \node[text centered, text width=4cm, fill=white] at (0,2) {Contact-Mode};
        \draw[draw=none, fill=gray!40!white, xshift=-0.5cm] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,-0.5) (-2,0.2) (-2,0.2) (-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.5)};
        \draw[very thick, red, xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=0.5] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05)};

        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.65cm, yshift=0.4cm, rotate=20]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0.3,0);
        \coordinate (c) at (0.15,-0.26);
        \coordinate (d) at (2,0);
        \draw[fill=black] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
        \draw (b) -- (d);
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \node[text centered, text width=4cm, fill=white] at (0,2) {Non-Contact-Mode};
        \draw[draw=none, fill=gray!40!white, xshift=-0.5cm] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,-0.5) (-2,0.2) (-2,0.2) (-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.5)};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt, segment length=3pt}, thick, red, xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=5] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05)};

        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.62cm, yshift={0.48cm+5}, rotate=18]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0.3,0);
        \coordinate (c) at (0.15,-0.26);
        \coordinate (d) at (2,0);
        \draw[fill=gray, gray] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
        \draw[gray] (b) -- (d);
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.65cm, yshift={0.4cm+5}, rotate=20]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0.3,0);
        \coordinate (c) at (0.15,-0.26);
        \coordinate (d) at (2,0);
        \draw[fill=black] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
        \draw (b) -- (d);
        \end{scope}
        \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, the only thing that needs to change is the pathmorphing in this line:

```
\draw[decorate, decoration={snake, amplitude=2pt, segment length=3pt}, thick, red, xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=5] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05)};
```

I basically want a snake pathmorphing that only affects the x-coordinates of the path. In other words: I want a sine with its center moving along a defined path.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like Ti*k*Z automatically used the [Frenet–Serret Coordinate System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas) to draw the decoration. To undo this, we need to reset the rotation/scaling/slanting part of the current transformation but keep the shifting part --- this is what `\pgftransformresetnontranslations` is claimed to do.

So modify the definition of `zigzag` from `pgflibrarydecorations.pathmorphing.code.tex` to get

```
\pgfdeclaredecoration{hopping}{up from center}{
  \state{up from center}[width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength, next state=big down]
  {
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{big down}[switch if less than=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to center finish,
                   width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                   next state=big up]
  {
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{big up}[switch if less than=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to center finish,
                 width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                 next state=big down]
  {
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{center finish}[width=0pt, next state=final]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}
```

and then apply them

[image]

Here is the complete example

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots,pgfplotstable}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.5.1, every axis/.append style={font=\small}}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclaredecoration{hopping}{up from center}{
  \state{up from center}[width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength, next state=big down]
  {
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{big down}[switch if less than=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to center finish,
                   width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                   next state=big up]
  {
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{big up}[switch if less than=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength to center finish,
                 width=+.5\pgfdecorationsegmentlength,
                 next state=big down]
  {
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfqpoint{.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
  }
  \state{center finish}[width=0pt, next state=final]{
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointorigin}
  }
  \state{final}
  {
    \pgftransformresetnontranslations
    \pgfpathlineto{\pgfpointdecoratedpathlast}
  }
}




    \begin{tikzpicture}[auto, thick]

        \node[text centered, text width=4cm, fill=white] at (0,2) {Contact-Mode};
        \draw[draw=none, fill=gray!40!white, xshift=-0.5cm] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,-0.5) (-2,0.2) (-2,0.2) (-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.5)};
        \draw[very thick, red, xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=0.5] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05)};

        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.65cm, yshift=0.4cm, rotate=20]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0.3,0);
        \coordinate (c) at (0.15,-0.26);
        \coordinate (d) at (2,0);
        \draw[fill=black] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
        \draw (b) -- (d);
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift=7cm]
        \node[text centered, text width=4cm, fill=white] at (0,2) {Non-Contact-Mode};
        \draw[draw=none, fill=gray!40!white, xshift=-0.5cm] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,-0.5) (-2,0.2) (-2,0.2) (-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.05) (3,-0.5)};
        \draw[decorate, decoration={hopping, amplitude=3pt, segment length=3pt}, thick, red, xshift=-0.5cm, yshift=5] plot [smooth, tension=0.7] coordinates {(-2,0.2) (-1.5,0) (-1,0.1) (-0.6,0.05) (-0.3,0.3) (0,0.1) (0.7,-0.1) (0.9,0) (1.1,-0.1) (1.5,0.2) (2,0) (2.7,0.05) (3,-0.05)};

        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.62cm, yshift={0.48cm+5}, rotate=18]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0.3,0);
        \coordinate (c) at (0.15,-0.26);
        \coordinate (d) at (2,0);
        \draw[fill=gray, gray] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
        \draw[gray] (b) -- (d);
        \end{scope}

        \begin{scope}[xshift=0.65cm, yshift={0.4cm+5}, rotate=20]
        \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
        \coordinate (b) at (0.3,0);
        \coordinate (c) at (0.15,-0.26);
        \coordinate (d) at (2,0);
        \draw[fill=black] (a) -- (b) -- (c) -- cycle;
        \draw (b) -- (d);
        \end{scope}
        \end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's a very posh way of saying it walks over the curve :) If you instead use sine and cosine paths then this becomes a snake too. And instead of resetting the transformation which you might need later you can use `\pgfdecoratedangle` to rotate back,

Comment: @percusse While writing the answer I was not sure if sine/cosine is effective in such scale. Physics tells us that it should be sine/cosine but I guess `line join=round` is enough to fool our eyes. Ti*k*Z kept reporting `dimension too large` so I did not want to play around but gave a brute way instead. By the way, thanks for your information.

Comment: Thanks, Symbol 1, that's actually what I was looking for. But the I would love to see the improvement percusse suggested. Unfortunately I have no idea what I have to change in your code to change it to sines, I actually don't even see where the zigzag came in. :D